# How to create a single drawingpanel that uses multiple classes to create graphics

Tags: java, class, graphics

I am looking for a starting point, not an answer, more trying to understand the concept. How to get all the windows on to only one panel/window?

Creates the `FacebookPerson`:

```
public class FacebookPerson{

private String myName;
protected String myMood;
protected Facebook myfacebook;

public FacebookPerson(String name){
  myName = name;
  myfacebook = new Facebook(myName);
  //System.out.println("FacebookPerson_Graphics's constructor");
}

public FacebookPerson(){

}

public String getName(){
  return myName;
}

public void setMood(String newMood){
 myMood = newMood;
 myfacebook.setContent(myMood);
}

public String getMood(){
  return myMood;
}

}
```

This is the Code that creates and edits:

```
package facebook;

import java.awt.*;

public class Facebook{

private String name;
private String content;
DrawingPanel panel;
private Graphics g;

public Facebook(String nm){
   content = "undefined";
   name = nm;

   // Create the drawing panel
   panel =new DrawingPanel(200,150);
   g = panel.getGraphics();
   // display name
   g.drawString(name+"'s mood is undefined.", 20, 75);
  }

public void setContent(String newContent){
content = newContent;
    if(content.equals("happy")){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        // display mood
        g.drawString(name+"'s mood is:"+ "happy", 20, 75);
    }
    else{
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(name+"'s mood is:"+ content, 20, 75);
    }
 }

      public String getContent(){
        return content;
  }



}
```

Creates the user interface to implement the two classes:

```
 package facebook;

 import java.util.*;

 public class testFacebook{


 public static void main (String[] args){

// Prompt user to enter the number of facebookpresons
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of facebookpresons to be created: ");
int numP=0;
while(true){
    try{
        numP = userInput.nextInt();
        userInput.nextLine();
        if(numP>0 && numP<=9)  // accept the number if it is within range. Here we define the range to be from 1 to 5. 
            break;
        else
            System.out.println("the number is out of range [1, 9]! enter again");
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("invalid input. Enter an integer number!");
        userInput.nextLine();
    }
}

FacebookPerson[] fbp = new FacebookPerson[numP];

//Ask the user to enter the name for each person, and create the persons
for(int i=0; i< numP; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter the name for person "+ (i+1)+ ":");
    String name = userInput.nextLine();
    fbp[i] = new FacebookPerson(name);
}
System.out.println("-------select a person and type the mood below--------");

//Ask the user to set the mood for a person, and update the mood, enter "####" to exit
while(true){
    System.out.println("Enter the name for a person (enter #### to exit):");
    String name = userInput.nextLine();
    if(name.equals("####"))
         System.exit(0);
    int personID = -1;
    for(int i=0; i< numP; i++){
        if(fbp[i].getName().equals(name)){
            personID = i;
            break;  // break the for loop
        }
    }
    if(personID!=-1){  // found the person, otherwise personID should still be -1
        System.out.println("Enter the mood for the person:");
        String mood = userInput.nextLine();
        fbp[personID].setMood(mood);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("unrecognized name!");
} // end while

} // end main

}
```

Comment: Lets start by not doing `g = panel.getGraphics();`, this is not how custom painting works

Comment: I know understand why you should not  use g =panel.getGraphics();, but I do not understand the concept of an interface, my professor has yet to cover that.

Comment: Well I suggest you take the time to do a little research of your own. You can use a plain class, but an interface is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by not doing `g = panel.getGraphics();`, this is not how custom painting works.  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done.

Start by defining a concept of something that is "paintable" or "drawable" (use an interface which defines the entry point by which something that can paint, can paint something that is paintable)

```
public interface Drawable {
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JComponent parent); // Any other parameters that might be useful...
}
```

Anything that you want to be painted on your "drawable surface" should implement this interface.

Create a "drawable surface" which can take a list of `Drawable` objects and, well, draw them...

```
public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {
    private List<Drawable> drawables;

    public DrawablePane() {
        drawables = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void add(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.add(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    public void remove(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.remove(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            drawable(g2d, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As an idea...